# Alerting viewbox field on OSM page not working using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Running:

```
javascript: alert(document.getElementById('viewbox').innerHTML)
```

at http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/

doesn't seem to return the value in the field **viewbox** i.e. it should be `-120.06,46.87,120.06,-46.87` when you load the page.

What other methods can I use to alert this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `document.getElementById('viewbox').value`